# Access Query - Return all rows with matching number until another field has a specific value

Tags: ms-access

I currently have a quite large Excel sheet with a lot of VBA that I would like to move into Access if possible to speed it up using queries instead of a bunch of loops, if statements, etc.  The main stopping point right now is working with the orders data.

The data is downloaded in a format similar to below (I've simplified it greatly):

```
Order Number        Operation          Sequence
A1                  0                  1
A1                  0                  2
A1                  L                  3
A1                  L                  4
A2                  L                  1
A2                  0                  2
A3                  L                  1
A4                  0                  1
A4                  L                  2
A4                  L                  3
A4                  L                  4
```

In Excel, I am able to just loop through the rows using the order number and stop when the operation is "L".  I would like to go through each row using the order number and delete all further sequences after the first "L" is reached.  The expected return from the top table would be:

```
Order Number        Operation          Sequence
A1                  0                  1
A1                  0                  2
A1                  L                  3

A2                  L                  1

A3                  L                  1
A4                  0                  1
A4                  L                  2
```

The blank/missing rows are what should be deleted from the table.

Current table
[image: Access Table Design]

Comment: From what I just found it appears that SQL is not able to determine the previous or next records so I may be stuck doing this in VBA... http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showpost.php?p=601014&postcount=3

Comment: It can be done with SQL queries, as long as your Access table also has a Primary Key field but it is much simpler to do with VBA.

Comment: @SunKnight0: Indeed. One loop in VBA through the records/rows and you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this but it will give you a good starting point. It assumes your Access table is properly imported with a RecordID Primary Key:

```
DELETE * FROM OrderData WHERE RecordID IN (
    SELECT RecordID FROM OrderData INNER JOIN
        (SELECT OrderNumber, MIN(Sequence) AS LGS FROM OrderData WHERE Operation='L' GROUP BY OrderNumber) LGR
        ON OrderData.OrderNumber=LGR.OrderNumber AND OrderData.Sequence>LGR.LGS )
```

What it does is first get the MIN(Sequence) with 'L' Operation for each Order Number, then get all the RecordIDs where Sequence is higher than that and use it as a DELETE condition.

Comment: I did import it with a primary key but it is not sorted so that all orders are together and in ascending order using sequence.  I have since sorted it but that means the keys are no longer in numerical order. Will that be a problem?

Comment: No, the Primary Key does not need to be in order, just unique. The Sequence field is the only order sensitive field in this query.

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error on this but not showing me what/where is the issue.

Comment: If you post the query exactly as it is written I can take a look.

Comment: I used exactly what you provided in the SQL view of the query.  The table with the data is "OrderData", ID field is "RecordID", order number field is "Order Number", Operation field is "Operation, and Sequence field is "Sequence".

Comment: You have to use your actual table/field names, not my examples. Without seeing the actual code I can't troubleshoot a syntax error. My first guess would be that you are using a name with space in it without enclosing it in brackets `Order Number` => `[Order Number]`

Comment: I've added a picture of the table to the original post, I did try changing Order_Number to OrderNumber to match the table but still getting the error.

Comment: I can't find a syntax error in a piece of code I can't see.

Comment: The code is exactly what you posted except Order_Number is OrderNumber.

Comment: Test each component individually. Start with `SELECT Order_Number, MIN(Sequence) AS LGS FROM OrderData WHERE Operation='L' GROUP BY Order_Number` then test `SELECT RecordID FROM OrderData JOIN
  (SELECT Order_Number, MIN(Sequence) AS LGS FROM OrderData WHERE Operation='L' GROUP BY Order_Number) LGR
  ON OrderData.Order_Number=LGR.Order_Number AND OrderData.Sequence>LGR.LGS`

Comment: `SELECT RecordID FROM OrderData JOIN (SELECT Order_Number, MIN(Sequence) AS LGS FROM OrderData WHERE Operation='L' GROUP BY Order_Number) LGR ON OrderData.Order_Number=LGR.Order_Number AND OrderData.Sequence>LGR.LGS` = Syntax error in FROM clause. It then specifically highlights JOIN.

Comment: Ah yes, Access is much pickier about keywords that other SQL systems. use "INNER JOIN" instead of "JOIN"

Comment: Both pieces now run fine, but now running the original code with modifications give me "Query must have at least one destination field."

Comment: Hmm, try `DELETE * FROM` instead of `DELETE FROM`

Comment: Code works great, thank you! Can you update your answer to show `DELETE * FROM OrderData WHERE RecordID IN (
    SELECT RecordID FROM OrderData INNER JOIN
        (SELECT OrderNumber, MIN(Sequence) AS LGS FROM OrderData WHERE Operation<>'0' GROUP BY OrderNumber) LGR
        ON OrderData.OrderNumber=LGR.OrderNumber AND OrderData.Sequence>LGR.LGS )` ?

Comment: Cool, that means you understand how it works so you can tweak it in the future if you need to.

Comment: Just a question here, is LGR a temporary table with LGS being a column in that table?

Comment: They are just aliases. For LGR think of it as the name of a query. In fact you could create LGR as a permanent query and then `INNER JOIN LGR`. As for LGS, it is just a name for the `MIN(Sequence)` value so we can reference it in `OrderData.Sequence>LGR.LGS`

Comment: Come to think of it, you can consider a saved query (called a View in other DBMS) as a temporary table, so in a way, yes.